# APACHE SOLR: Best Way to have multiple OR Conditions for same field

Tags: solr, lucene

I am new to SOLR , we have CRM data for Contacts and Companies which are in millions, we have switched to SOLR for fast search results.

PROBLEM: We have large inclusion and exclusion lists with names of companies or contacts. 
Ex: Include or Exclude : "company A" & "Company B" & "Company C" .... & "Company n"  where assume  n = 10000;

What would be the best way to do this kind of a query using SOLR.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED: 
Setting "q" ==> field_name: ("companyA" OR "companyB" ..... OR "Company n"); 
This works only for a list of 400 odd.

Looking forward for assistance on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the max number of boolean clauses: See here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml

Performance Hint: In your case I would think about packaging the inclusion and exclusion lists into a filter and letting the results cache for reuse.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for multiple reasons:

1. Check the way how you are querying Solr. Is it `GET` method or `POST`? If it is `GET` method then all the parameters are passed as the part of URL i.e. `http://<host:>q=field_name:(....)`. Maximum number of character a URL can have just **2048** defined universally by Microsoft. If your programatically formed URL has more than **2048** characters then either change the query model or make it `POST` call.
2. If #1 doesn't apply for your case, then check for `maxBooleanClauses` tag present in `solrConfig.xml` file. If it is missing then add it as per guidelines by Solr wiki.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#The_Query_Section

You can increase the value of `maxBooleanClauses` in `solrConfig.xml` to a desired level. By default the value for this is 1028.

Shishir